# How to find which folder in the file system in Mac OS X Yosemite(version 10.10.2 ) is an application writing data to?

Tags: macos

Activity Monitor shows Google Chrome is writing data constantly, I know why but I want to know where exactly in the File System is the data being written , the Folder I mean.[image]

Comment: You could run `lsof -p 90213` which lists all open filehandles. (90213 being the process ID)

Answer (score 1):

You can click on the (i) Icon at the top left corner of Activity Monitor to show process details.

There is a tab "Open files and ports".

Comment: thanks Thilo both of the answers helped but the file shows that Chrome is writing to some .localstorage file, it sure does but not just there.The actual thing is that a website saves the video somewhere in my system so that it does not have to buffer the next time I load the video, I am sure about that but can't find where it saves the videos. Do you have any idea how I can find it.Again, thanks a lot for the help.